# Each row in range skips every second value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop over all rows in the active worksheet and compare the values of a column.

However, it skips every second value.

The worksheet looks like this:

[image: Worksheet]

Code:

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim value As String

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    total = 0

    For Each r In ws.UsedRange.rows

        value = r.Cells(r.Row, 3).value

        If value = "Test" Then

            'Do something...
            total = total + 1

        End If

       Debug.Print ("Row: " & r.Row & " - Value: " & value)

    Next r

End Sub
```

The console shows this:

```
Row: 1 - Value: Col2
Row: 2 - Value: JohnDoe
Row: 3 - Value: JohnDoe
Row: 4 - Value: Test
Row: 5 - Value: Blabla
Row: 6 - Value: Blabla
Row: 7 - Value: 
Row: 8 - Value: 
Row: 9 - Value: 
Row: 10 - Value: 
Row: 11 - Value:
```

How do I fix this, so it does not skip every second value?

The reason I am using `UsedRange` instead of `for i = 1 to x`, is that I will not now the number of rows beforehand.

Comment: Don't use `UsedRange`... [Find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: @BigBen ws.UsedRange.rows in this case give the correct number of rows, so I don't think it will change anything.

Comment: Is your goal only to count `Test` in column `C:C`?

Comment: Please re-read the answer to that question and *don't* use `UsedRange`...

Comment: @JvdV my goal is to test if the value of column C is "Test" and then execute a number of commands. I simplified the example here

Comment: Then use [`FindNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) to only loop over cells that hold `Test`. Looping all cells is redundant. =)

Comment: Thank you @BigBen you were right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions:

1. Avoid using `UsedRange`: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) why.
2. Avoid looping over the `Rows` if you don't need to... also avoid referencing `r.Cells` as this will not be an *absolute* reference (i.e. relative to the whole sheet), but a *relative* reference based on `r`.

```
With ws
    Dim lastRow as Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 to lastRow
       If .Cells(i, "C").Value = "Test" Then
           ' do your stuff, though this loop is still inefficient
       End If
    Next
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution, thanks to @BigBen

```
Sub test_solution()

    'Variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim value As String
    Dim lastRow
    Dim i As Integer
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    total = 0

    With ws
        lastRow = Range("C" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For i = 1 To lastRow

        value = Cells(i, 3).value

        If value = "Test" Then

            'Do something

            total = total + 1

        End If

       Debug.Print ("Row: " & i & " - Value: " & value)

    Next i

End Sub
```

Gives correct output:

```
Row: 1 - Value: Col2
Row: 2 - Value: Test
Row: 3 - Value: JohnDoe
Row: 4 - Value: Test
Row: 5 - Value: JohnDoe
Row: 6 - Value: JohnDoe
Row: 7 - Value: Test
Row: 8 - Value: Blabla
Row: 9 - Value: Blabla
Row: 10 - Value: Test
Row: 11 - Value: Blabla
```